# perform one transaction for multiple threads

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, transactions, forkjoinpool

I have a method that persist data before calling multiple threads to perform other actions in parallel:

```
public List<dtos> myMethod(data)
    repository.saveAll(data);
    ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(4);
    return pool.invoke(new recursiveTask(data));
}
```

I want myMethod to be transactional ( if one thread throws error a rollback will be performed and repository.saveAll(data) would not save data), in Spring we use the annotation @Transactional, but here we have multiple threads and it is not working.

Is there any way to perform this ?

Thanks.

Comment: I would question the design choice. In any case this pattern seems like the way to do it: https://www.baeldung.com/cs/saga-pattern-microservices

Comment: Try a single-threaded, focusing on being fully correct (roll back all things, or commit all things). After that, measure your system to understand if performance is good enough or not. If it's "too slow", there may very well be other things to adjust before introducing parallel threads into the solution.